# How can I used the same dropdown list across multiple tabs in a sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with multiple tabs in it. One for every week of the year. On one of those tabs, called MasterList, I also have a list of items from A1 to A50. I've created a dropdown of those items and it works as expected. When I copy that same dropdown and paste it into another cell in MasterList, it also works as expected.

When I go to one of the other tabs, Week1 for example, and setup a data validation rule for cell C4, I use the criteria of =MasterList!A1:A50. This works as expected.

I want to then use the same criteria for C4 through C51 on the Week1 so that basically I have an entire column of dropdowns that allows me to select one of the options created in MasterList. I would also then do this for columns D through I.

The issue I'm running into, is that when I copy cell C4 and paste it into C5, I lose 1 of the list items. When I paste into C6, I'm missing 2 of the list items. I know that this is happening because the criteria is changing to =MasterList!A2:A51 and =MasterList!A3:A52 respectively. Is there a way to add a list to all of the cells I mentioned above without having to modify the criteria in every single one of them?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). See [absolute and relative references](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/googlespreadsheets/types-of-cell-references/1/).

Answer (score 0):

A friend actually helped be with the answer, which is embarrassing because sheets also gives you the answer right in the criteria section of the data validation.

I updated the criteria to "=MasterList!$A$1:$A$50" and now it works regardless of where I paste the copied cell.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISvNj.png]